# Converting an IP Address string to exactly 4 bytes in Python

Tags: python, sockets, ip, byte

So this is very simple, but I'm having trouble getting this to work.  I want to, for example, if the incoming IP address string is '168.108.114.22', convert this to a bytes object like:

```
\xA8\x6C\x72\x16
```

Basically each part of the IP address is converted to it's hexadecimal equivalent.

I've tried so many ways but couldn't get what I want.  String manipulation, using socket.inet_aton, packing, etc.  I want to be able to send  these bytes over a socket and then receive and parse them at the other end, but I am having trouble just getting my bytes object created and looking like that.

Answer (score 4):

Python's [`inet_aton`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html?highlight=aton#socket.inet_aton) function should do what you need, it does return a string containing exactly 4 bytes:

```
import socket

print socket.inet_aton('168.108.114.22')
print socket.inet_aton('65.66.67.68')
```

These would display:

```
¨lr
ABCD
```

And to convert the four characters back again using [`inet_ntoa`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html?highlight=aton#socket.inet_ntoa):

```
print socket.inet_ntoa('\xA8\x6C\x72\x16')
print socket.inet_ntoa('ABCD')
```

Giving:

```
65.66.67.68
```

Comment: How would I convert this back to the IP address on the other end of the socket?  If I sent it through this way, after converting using inet_aton.

Comment: [ntoa](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html?highlight=aton#socket.inet_ntoa) i.e. network-to-ascii (they all come from good ol' C)

Answer (score 1):

this

```
ip='168.108.114.22'

b_out = bytes(map(int,ip.split('.')))
print(b_out)
```

on python 3 produces

```
b'\xa8lr\x16'
```

which should be what you are looking for, if I understand correctly.

Note: there are more specific and optimized utility functions to manipulate IP addresses